# Will other instances of a class be able to access a static variable in another?

Tags: java, classloader, static-variables

I have a class that I know will be loaded by a URLClassLoader for each instance of it, so if I have a static variable in one, will the other instances be able to access it?

For example, Class MyClass is loaded by ClassLoader A and ClassLoader B, and I want to know if MyClass loaded by A will have the same static fields as MyClass loaded by B.

So basically, will the following statement always be true:

```
A.loadClass("MyClass").getField("MyField").get(null).equals(B.loadClass("MyClass").getField("MyField").get(null));
```

Comment: @Arnaud, regarding your suggested edit: Formatting the code is indeed a good thing to do. But there's no reason to "simplify" the number of tags. Using up all 5 is even encouraged, because it helps to classify the questions on the site and assists the automated algorithms in linked possibly related questions. A tag about static variables *definitely* belongs on this question. Just something to keep in mind for future edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately @Dinesh/@DAJ's answer is incorrect. (@Romain's maybe too, but the wording is hard to parse.)

Suppose you have a class `a.b.C` and you arrange that the same class gets loaded by two different classloaders.  According to the specifications, you will end up with two distinct `Class` objects with the fully qualified name `a.b.C`, and from the type system perspective two distinct types.  Each of the types will have a different set of static variables.

The primary reference for this is [JLS 4.3.4](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.3.4) - paragraphs 2 and 3.

You can infer that each reference type that is distinct (at runtime) will have a distinct set of statics from [JLS 4.12.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.12.3), [JLS 8.3.1.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.3.1.1), [JLS 12.4](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.4), and other parts of the language spec.

---

> So basically, will the following statement always be true:

```
A.loadClass("MyClass").getField("myField").get(null)
    .equals(B.loadClass("MyClass").getField("myField").get(null));
```

In general it won't.

It will always be true in *some* cases, depending on how `MyClass` initializes `myField`.  For instance, if the field is initialized to a literal String, then it will.

(The trick to observing this is to arrange that `MyClass` is *actually loaded* by the two classloaders `A` and `B`, and not by a common ancestor classloader.)

Comment: Thanks so much :D Great answer. Now how do I give rep? O.o

Answer (score 2):

Static variables are unique across classloaders. (The references to these that is) The values might be the same. Using equals will work, using == will not.

EDIT: Each ClassLoader will load a different class (They can even be different versions). The initialized statics will be different. Two different classes from different ClassLoaders can have variables (static or not) that are identical in value.

Comment: you should explain what you mean by "unique across classloaders".

Comment: And is it also true that A.loadClass("MyClass").equals(B.loadClass("MyClass")) will be false?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it shouldn't matter who loads the class. As long as the fields are static, they should be the same. Did you try to experiment with some code?

Comment: Ah, no I haven't. The way it's currently set up, there's no need for concurrent instances, but soon there will be.

Comment: Usually, you want to quickly make up some code and try it out. For example, just make a static class. Load it in another class using different loaders and compare the values. By definition 'static' should behave like static in all circumstances. If it behaves differently then it violates the guarantee that the Java language provides the programmer.

Comment: Yeah, like 90% of the time I do, I just didn't have time to do so (I haven't used the URLClassLoader before and it was like 10 at night :P)